# TYPO3 6.2: How to limit the number of displayed links in Related pages (based on keywords)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In TYPO3 6.2 the Special Menu "Related pages (based on keywords)", shows a list of the selected page and all other pages, which have one or more keywords, entered in the page properties, in common.

The problem is that my site has lots of pages with the same keywords and hence in some pages the number of displayed links is excessive.

The question is how could I limit the number of displayed links?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the menu is generated by typoscript, which is the case for TYPO3 6.2, you could configure the menu generation like any other typoscript menu object.

Any menu object has the property `maxItems`  (see [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/6.2/en-us/MenuObjects/CommonProperties/Index.html) ). You need to look for the definition of the content elements which should be beneath `tt_content`:

```
tt_content.menu.20.6.maxItems = 10
```

For newer TYPO3 versions the place of TS-defined CEs has changed up to the realisation of CEs by fluid. But still the property `maxItems` is available.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have tried coding in Typoscript and also including the maxItems using Info/Modify.  No way, the maxItems is ignored. Of course I'm not a TypoScript expert but I'm using TYPO3 for some 18 years or so.

Comment: is your menu generated with a menu content-element or is it generated by typoscript as a part of the general page rendering? do you use the default rendering engine (CSC) or do you use others (fluid, DCE, flux, Templa Voila, ...)?

Comment: I'm updating to version TYPO3 7.6.32. I'll be back ASAP.

Comment: Well, as always TYPO3 upgrading is a pain in you know where. But it is done anyway.
Regarding the subject: Same problem with 7.6.32.  maxItems  ignored.

Comment: Forgot to answer your comment. The menu is generated with a menu content-element and the CSC.